# How do I check if an amount of days exceeds the actual maximum of a month?

Tags: java

I am working on an application where I have a certain amount of money that needs to be paid each month, and then I am creating two input fields where the user can enter a start date and an end date to see how much money needs to be paid within a certain range of months or days.

After entering the dates I want to calculate how many days there are between the start date and the end date.

```
    long diffInDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
```

The next thing I want to check is if the number of days match the max number of dates within a month

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int daysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

The calculation should be:

If amount to be paid is 100 and diffInDays equals getActualMaximum
return 100

If amount to be paid is 100 and diffInDays is 12
return the value of 100/12

If amount to be paid is 100 and the dates entered match an exact range of months (eg 01/01/2024 - 01/03/2024)
return 200

If amount to be paid is 100 and diffInDays equals getActualMaximum + 12
return 100 + 100/12

I am making the calculation within a filter:

```
.filter(orderLine -> DateTimeUtils.isWithin(startDate, endDate))
.map(OrderLines::getAmount)
.reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
.divide(new BigDecimal(diffInDays), RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
```

The problem is that this calculation only looks at days. As I said, if the amount of days equal the max amount of days in a month, I don't want the calculation to run. It should just return the amount without dividing it. The same should happen if the user input is an exact number of months eg. startDate = 01/01/2024 and endDate = 01/03/2024.

I would need to make a condition that looks something like this:

```
if(diffInDays == daysInMonth || diffInDays == daysInMonth + 1) {

.filter(orderLine -> DateTimeUtils.isWithin(startDate, endDate))
    .map(OrderLines::getAmount)
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)

}
```

But how can I take multiple months into such a condition? And what if the user enters a range of days that corresponds to 1 month + 5 days. Then I still need to make the calculation for those 5 days, but ignore the first month.

I can't wrap my head around it

Comment: Pardon me, but your problem description is not clear (to me, at least). `Calendar.getInstance();` returns the current date, doesn't it? How is that related to the user-entered dates? And why are you using class `Calendar` ? Shouldn't you be using [enum] [Month](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) which has method `maxLength()` ? What happens if the user enters today as start date, i.e. 21-March-2024 and end date of 21-April-2024? `diffInDays` will be 31, i.e. number of days in March in which case you don't want to do the calculation, right?

Comment: As @Abra says, don’t use `Calendar`. You are already using `ChronoUnit` and some other class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API (probably `LocalDate`?). Mixing in `Calendar` will give you nothing but trouble and needless conversions. `Calendar` had severe design problems and has been outdated for the last 10 years.

Comment: You may for example get the number of days in a month from [`YearMonth.lengthOfMonth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html#lengthOfMonth()).

Comment: Maybe you want this (sorry, it’s not clear): Find the number of whole months from `ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between()`. Add this number of months to the start date. Then use `ChronoUnit.DAYS` to find the excess days.

Comment: If amount is 100, what needs to be paid if difference is 1 day? What if one day short of a month, for example 28/01/2024 . 27/02/2024 (30 days) or 28/02/2024 - 27/03/2024 (28 days)? Asking because I don’t think you mean this: *If amount to be paid is 100 and diffInDays is 12 return the value of 100/12*.

Comment: Even better and simpler (depending on your exact requirements, which remain unclear): Use `Period,between()` to obtain the amount of calendar time between the two dates as a `Period` object. Use its `toTotalMonths` and `getDays` methods to obtain the months and days between the two dates. I suspect that this is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use `Calendar`. That terribly flawed class is now legacy, like both `Date` classes, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

### *java.time*

Use only the modern *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2024 , 1 , 23 ) ;
```

Count elapsed days as you did.

```
long daysElapsed = TimeUnit.DAYS.between( start , end ) ;
```

To represent a specific month of year, use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

```
YearMonth startYearMonth = YearMonth.from( start ) ;
```

Interrogate for length of month.

```
int startMonthLength = startYearMonth.lengthOfMonth() ;
```

I can’t help any further with certainty, as I am unable to understand your description of business rules.

### List of dates per month

Perhaps it would help you to group a sublist of your dates per month. Doing so is quite easy with stream, lambda, and method reference.

```java
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 23 );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.MARCH , 13 );

Stream < LocalDate > stream = start.datesUntil( stop );

SequencedMap < YearMonth, List < LocalDate > > mapMonthToDates =
        stream
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                YearMonth :: from ,
                                TreeMap :: new ,
                                Collectors.mapping( Function.identity( ) , Collectors.toList( ) )
                        )
                );
```

We use a [`SequencedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html) (`TreeMap`) here to keep the months in order.

```
mapMonthToDates = {2024-01=[2024-01-23, 2024-01-24, 2024-01-25, 2024-01-26, 2024-01-27, 2024-01-28, 2024-01-29, 2024-01-30, 2024-01-31], 2024-02=[2024-02-01, 2024-02-02, 2024-02-03, 2024-02-04, 2024-02-05, 2024-02-06, 2024-02-07, 2024-02-08, 2024-02-09, 2024-02-10, 2024-02-11, 2024-02-12, 2024-02-13, 2024-02-14, 2024-02-15, 2024-02-16, 2024-02-17, 2024-02-18, 2024-02-19, 2024-02-20, 2024-02-21, 2024-02-22, 2024-02-23, 2024-02-24, 2024-02-25, 2024-02-26, 2024-02-27, 2024-02-28, 2024-02-29], 2024-03=[2024-03-01, 2024-03-02, 2024-03-03, 2024-03-04, 2024-03-05, 2024-03-06, 2024-03-07, 2024-03-08, 2024-03-09, 2024-03-10, 2024-03-11, 2024-03-12]}
```

### Prorate monthly fee

If you are trying to prorate a monthly fee, this code may get you headed in the right direction. Adjust the math to suit your accountants.

```java
package work.basil.example.time;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class DatesPerMonth
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 23 );
        LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.MARCH , 13 );

        Stream < LocalDate > stream = start.datesUntil( stop );

        SequencedMap < YearMonth, List < LocalDate > > mapMonthToDates =
                stream
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.groupingBy(
                                        YearMonth :: from ,
                                        TreeMap :: new ,
                                        Collectors.mapping( Function.identity( ) , Collectors.toList( ) )
                                )
                        );
        System.out.println( "mapMonthToDates = " + mapMonthToDates );

        SequencedCollection < MonthlyFee > monthlyFees = getMonthlyFees( mapMonthToDates );
        monthlyFees.forEach( System.out :: println );
    }

    private static SequencedCollection < MonthlyFee > getMonthlyFees ( final SequencedMap < YearMonth, List < LocalDate > > mapMonthToDates )
    {
        final BigDecimal pricePerMonth = new BigDecimal( "200" );
        SequencedCollection < MonthlyFee > monthlyFees = new ArrayList <>( mapMonthToDates.size( ) );
        final int scale = 2; // Number of decimal places.
        final RoundingMode bankersRounding = RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN;
        for ( Map.Entry < YearMonth, List < LocalDate > > yearMonthListEntry : mapMonthToDates.entrySet( ) )
        {
            YearMonth yearMonth = yearMonthListEntry.getKey( );
            int monthLength = yearMonth.lengthOfMonth( );
            BigDecimal costPerDay = pricePerMonth.divide( new BigDecimal( monthLength ) , 2 , bankersRounding );
            List < LocalDate > listOfDates = yearMonthListEntry.getValue( );
            int countOfDaysInList = listOfDates.size( );
            BigDecimal cost = costPerDay.multiply( new BigDecimal( countOfDaysInList ) ).setScale( 2 , bankersRounding );
            System.out.println( "Cost: " + cost + " = " + monthLength + " days at cost per day: " + costPerDay );
            monthlyFees.add( new MonthlyFee( yearMonth , listOfDates , cost ) );
        }
        return monthlyFees;
    }

    record MonthlyFee( YearMonth yearMonth , List < LocalDate > dates , BigDecimal cost ) { }
}
```

```
Cost: 58.05 = 31 days at cost per day: 6.45
Cost: 200.10 = 29 days at cost per day: 6.90
Cost: 77.40 = 31 days at cost per day: 6.45
MonthlyFee[yearMonth=2024-01, dates=[2024-01-23, 2024-01-24, 2024-01-25, 2024-01-26, 2024-01-27, 2024-01-28, 2024-01-29, 2024-01-30, 2024-01-31], cost=58.05]
MonthlyFee[yearMonth=2024-02, dates=[2024-02-01, 2024-02-02, 2024-02-03, 2024-02-04, 2024-02-05, 2024-02-06, 2024-02-07, 2024-02-08, 2024-02-09, 2024-02-10, 2024-02-11, 2024-02-12, 2024-02-13, 2024-02-14, 2024-02-15, 2024-02-16, 2024-02-17, 2024-02-18, 2024-02-19, 2024-02-20, 2024-02-21, 2024-02-22, 2024-02-23, 2024-02-24, 2024-02-25, 2024-02-26, 2024-02-27, 2024-02-28, 2024-02-29], cost=200.10]
MonthlyFee[yearMonth=2024-03, dates=[2024-03-01, 2024-03-02, 2024-03-03, 2024-03-04, 2024-03-05, 2024-03-06, 2024-03-07, 2024-03-08, 2024-03-09, 2024-03-10, 2024-03-11, 2024-03-12], cost=77.40]
```